# update the table data in all the schema at a time

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I am working with oracle database. suppose there are  five different `schema`,there is table called `model_num` in all the `schema`, and suppose i am updating some rows to `model_num` table in one of the schema. so is it possible to update `model_num` table from all the `schemas` once i update it in one schema?

can anyone help me how to do it?

Comment: Do you want to change the table definition or update record data that is in the table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `model_num` tables contain the same information, why you don't just:

1. Create one table in a schema, grant select on other schemas? update your single table and other shemas will see all informations.
2. Create one table in a schema and views based on that table for the other schemas?

If you have almost the same information, you can do other tricks, but we need more information from you. How your tables differ?

Comment: Hi Florin your 1st point is shows that u have understood my question correctly. now can u please give me syntax how to grant select on other schemas?

Comment: Sure: `grant select on model_num to your_other_schema;`.